# Prevent user from entering invalid dateformat in Datepicker Textbox without disabling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a requirement where user should be able to enter date in a textbox via manually typing as well as using the datepicker. I want to prevent the user from typing invalid date formats in the textbox.

For Example : I am using `mm/dd/yy` format, user should not be able to type more than `12` in the mm column and in the date column should be filled in accordance with the month(30/31/28)and so on.

I have tried using the constrainInput property of datepicker class but it does not work as expected.

```js
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
   constrainInput:"true",
   dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy"
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="datepicker1"/>
```

Comment: you could use [Masked Input Plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) this will help you more to validate your date format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example use inputmask with datepicker, you can refer:

```js
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
   constrainInput:"true",
   dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy"
});


var maskConfig = {
      leapday: "29-02-",
      separator: "/",
      showMaskOnHover: false,
      showMaskOnFocus: false,
      placeholder: "__/__/____"
}

$('#datepicker1').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy',maskConfig);
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<input type="text" id="datepicker1"/>
```

Comment: on a sidenote can you tell me. why input mask is not recognizing "mm/dd/yy" format? it is working only when the parameter is "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: you could refer in document of inputmask https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask , it only support alias year with pattern is 'yyyy' not 'yy'